# Change date format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently creating a warehouse stock management for my company and upon the data structure for the date, it automatically sets to (year-month-day) as a default format and I would like to change the format to MM/DD/YYYY specification.

However, I have checked the conversion format but it did not specify how to convert the entire column data into a specific format. Only show today's date with a format in which I intended to convert.

Is there any simple conversion to this problem without having to recreate the table again?

[image]

Table Schema

Comment: If you are storing your date correctly as a `datetime` datatype then, I can't emphasise this enough, **it has no format**! You should only be formatting for display, really in your front end, not your database. But if you wish to do it in a `select` statement then use `format`.

Comment: Can you show us your table schema ?

Comment: @Squirrel i have added the schema above

Comment: what is the data type for `DATEOFSUPPLY` ?

Comment: @Squirrel as 'date' .

Comment: you are doing fine. `DATEOFSUPPLY` is `DATE` data type. DON'T change it. Date is not store in `SQL Server` in any specific format. It is in some binary format. You format the date to the format you required in your client where the date is shown. What you see in `SSMS` as `YYYY-MM-DD` is how `SSMS` display the date

Answer (score 2):

You should store the stock date as a bona fide date or datetime column in SQL Server.  Then, if you want to *view* that date a certain way, e.g. as `MM/DD/YYYY`, use the `CONVERT` function for that.  For example:

```
SELECT
    GETDATE() AS date_orig,                          -- 2020-09-23 03:45:06.343
    CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101) AS date_new;    -- 09/23/2020
```

Comment: @DaleK Plenty of reasons.  First, the OP might be using a somewhat older version of SQL Server which does not support `FORMAT`.  Also, `CONVERT` might perform a bit better than `FORMAT`.

Comment: I would use `CONVERT()` instead of `FORMAT()` if `CONVERT()` can get the job done. From BOL `FORMAT relies on the presence of the .NET Framework Common Language Runtime (CLR).` As such I would assumed that performance of `CONVERT()` will be better.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is only viewed right? not like actual conversion into the data because I have tried to do what you required but it seems that it only illustrates today's date with the different formate or i am missing something here?

Comment: @PhạmQuốcMinhĐăng You might be missing something.  Dates are stored internally in SQL Server as binary data.  The point here is that it you want to _view_ your date column a certain way, then use something like `CONVERT` or `FORMAT`, but leave the original data as-is.